# Angular: activating components on screen using query parameters

Tags: angular

Angular: I have a requirement where there are a couple of tabs on the screen like-

URL to below screen - `base?tab=TAB_1`

```
 _____________________________________________________
|                                                     |
|  (Parent Component)                                 |
| _________________________                           |
|| *TAB_1* | TAB_2 | TAB_3 |                          |
||_________|_______|_______|________________________  |
||                                                  | |
||          TAB_1 component shown here              | |
||                                                  | |
||__________________________________________________| |
|_____________________________________________________|
```

and the user want to switch between the tabs using query parameters - ex. accessing `base?tab=TAB_2` will show Parent Component with TAB 2 selected and also clicking on TAB_3 updates the url to `base?tab=TAB_3` and the selected tab to `Tab_3`. Note that TAB_1, TAB_2 and TAB_3 are separate components.

I want to know on how to implement this kind of behavior. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Implementig component on every Tabs, using ParentChild or create dynamic components

Comment: This would be easier and cleaner if you’d use router params (/tab/tab1) probably..